# localStorage in Vue . Where need to use?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I want to use localStorage so that when the page is reloaded, the data is saved

I use vuex to follow person is registered on not. And want when page was loaded , person was registered

My Vuex:

```
export default {
    state:{
        isRegistered:false
    },
    actions:{
        registrate({commit}) {
            commit("login")
        },
        exit({commit}) {
            commit("logout")
        }
    },
    mutations:{
        login(state) {
            state.isRegistered=true;
        },
        logout(state) {
            state.isRegistered=false
        }
    },
    getters:{
        IS_REGISTERED(state){
            return state.isRegistered
        }
    }
}
```

My Links in Vue.js

```
<template>
    <header class="hat">
        <div class="header__buttons">
          
    
            <div v-if="IS_REGISTERED" id="exit--tittle">
                <button @click="exitFromSystem">Exit from system</button>
            </div>
    
            <router-link :to="{name:'registration'}">
                <button id="registration" v-if="!IS_REGISTERED">Registration</button>
            </router-link>
        </div>
    </header>
</template>


<script>
    methods: {
        ...mapActions(["exit"]),
        exitFromSystem() { 
            this.exit() // Look in Vuex
        },  
    },
</script>
```

the question itself:

where is it best to use localStorage to keep IS_REGISTERED on reload page?

Comment: in the state management code

Comment: @JaromandaX it's like in vuex: 
||||||||||||||||||||||||

actions:{
        registrate({commit}) {
            commit("login")
            localStorage.setItem('registration',true)
        },
}

|||||||||||||||||||
and if so, then how to change IS_REGISTRED later?

Comment: correct, yes, in vuex - perhaps I misunderstood your question

Comment: by the way, there's a plugin for vuex to use `localStorage` for persistence

Comment: @JaromandaX, yes,man, thank you very much.I fixed it myself, you can see my answer if you're interested

Comment: I haven't used Vuex since Pinia came out :p

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it myself,
*// npm->
npm install vuex-persistedstate
// OR
// yarn->
yarn add vuex-persistedstate*

im my store it was necessary to add like this:

```
import Vue from "vue"
import Vuex from "vuex"
import createPersistedState from "vuex-persistedstate";

export default new Vuex.Store({
   modules:{
       // 
   },
   plugins:[createPersistedState()]
}
```